# Centos Yum Repo Issues

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to enable the REMI repo by executing the below command:
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm

as a result I keep getting:
 package remi-release-5.10-1.el5.remi.noarch is already installed

I'm pretty sure it's not .... There is no .repo for this in /etc/yum.repos.d

Help please if possible!

Comment: Because a file that should be installed is missing in no way means the RPM isn't installed.  You should use rpm or yum to verify whether it's installed or not (`man rpm` and `man yum` if you're unsure how to do it).  When you verify that it actually is installed, uninstall it.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what version of CentOS you are using and also included the output from the suggested commands so folks can see the actual results. Of course installing or removing rpm's require either root or sudo to root...

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -qa | grep remi-release` will tell you if the rpm is installed.

`rpm -e remi-release` will remove the rpm.

`yum repolist` will show you what repos are available.

`yum repoinfo` will return more information about the available repos along with their associated `.repo` file names.

Comment: Thanks! Following this command I've tried rpm -ivh remi-release-5.10-1.el5.remi with no luck.. I would like to remove this RPM / Repo so I can install it again. It is not showing under repolist

Comment: Thanks for the update however, the remi repo entry is not showing in the repoinfo or repolist but when I go to try and install it, it says the RPM already exists

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the RPM, it should drop a file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` called `remi.repo`:-

```
$ rpm -qlp remi-release-5.rpm
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

If it's not there, and you're sure the RPM is installed, you should be able to remove the RPM with `rpm -e remi-release`.

Some useful commands for you:-

- `rpm -ql remi-release` - will list the files installed by the package `remi-release`
- `rpm -qi remi-release` - will show the info for the package

You can also add the `-p` option to the above, and specify a path to an RPM instead of a package name - that way you can see the info and files installed by the package without actually installing the package.